# How to add value into a variable or an array in PHP with format define?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 variable with value is string type, i want add it into a variable or an array in PHP with format `"('$a','$b','$c')"`. I trying to add it but my result is `$a,$b,$c` or `["$a","$b","$c"]`. This is my example code in PHP:

```
$a = "Vip";
$b = "Good";
$c = "Normal";

$array = array();
//$array = null;

array_push($array, $a, $b, $c);
$array = join(',', $array);
```

Comment: Why not simply create your array as `$array = array($a, $b, $c);`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you *actually* want. If you need an array, just write:

```
$array  = [$a, $b, $c];
```

If you need a string, I'd probably write:

```
$string = sprintf('%s, %s, %s', $a, $b, $c);
```

Or, if you need the brackets and quotes around the strings (as your given format seems to suggest):

```
$string = sprintf("('%s', '%s', '%s')", $a, $b, $c);
```

Of course, you could combine the two (an array, and use that to create a formatted string), but that probably isn't what you need:

```
$array = [$a, $b, $c];
$string = vsprintf("('%s', '%s', '%s')", $array);
```

Use `printf` or `echo` if you want to output the string directly.

The choice is yours... Make sure to check the docs on `sprintf` and/or `vsprintf` though

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helpful for me.